# Get the Value of HTML Attributes Using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer, I've selected some HTML elements using:

```
await page.$$( 'span.styleNumber' );
```

I can get the element's text using:

```
console.log( await ( await styleNumber.getProperty( 'innerText' ) ).jsonValue() );
```

How can I the value of the element's data-Color attribute?

Here is my script:

### HTML

```
<span class="styleNumber" data-Color="Blue">SG1000</span>
<span class="styleNumber" data-Color="Green">SG2000</span>
<span class="styleNumber" data-Color="Red">SG3000</span>
```

### Puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

( async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto( 'http://www.example.com/sample.php' );

    // Get a list of all elements.
    var styleNumbers = await page.$$( 'span.styleNumber' );

    // Print the style numbers.
    for( let styleNumber of styleNumbers ) {
        try {
            console.log( await ( await styleNumber.getProperty( 'innerText' ) ).jsonValue() );
        }
        catch( e ) {
            console.log( `Could not get the style number:`, e.message );
        }
    }

    await browser.close();
} )();
```

The above code would print:

```
SG1000
SG2000
SG3000
```

How can I get the value of the data-Color attributes? E.g.:

```
console.log( await ( await styleNumber.getAttribute( 'data-Color' ) ) ); // Blue
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can get attribute value with `evaluate` method.

```
await page.evaluate('document.querySelector("span.styleNumber").getAttribute("data-Color")')
```

---

#### Second way

`$$eval` method can also be used. Also attributes called as Array from variable

```
const attr = await page.$$eval("span.styleNumber", el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute("data-Color")));
```

Output will be

```
["Blue", "Green", "Red"]
```

---

### Your solution

```
const styleNumbers = await page.$$("span.styleNumber");

for( let styleNumber of styleNumbers ) {
    const attr = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("data-Color"), styleNumber);
}
```

Comment: For those who prefer to write out the argument for page.evaluate as JS:  

`await page.evaluate(() => 
  document.querySelector("span.styleNumber").getAttribute("data-Color")
)  `