# How would I get an element value by name using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to get the value of this

```
<input type="hidden" value="12345" name="InitiationTT">
```

But since it does not have an ID, I would like to retrieve the value by name. I first tried this:

```
const cii = await page.$("InitiationTT");
const init = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("value"), cii);
```

which did not work and threw `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')`, so then I tried this:

```
const cii = page.evaluate(() => {document.querySelector("input[name=InitiationTT]").value});
```

which gave me `Promise { <pending> }` and so I finally tried this:

```
const cii = document.querySelector("input[name=InitiationTT]").value;
```

Which gave me `ReferenceError: document is not defined` so I am assuming that is because I am using NodeJS(?)

These 3 methods did not work and I do not know if Puppeteer has a way of getting a value of an element by it's name. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your selector is correct. Furthermore, the `value` property should be available on the `<input>` element.

```js
const r = await page.$eval('input[name="InitiationTT"]', ({ value }) => value); // 12345
```

**Reference:** [How to get element value in puppeteer](https://codedec.com/tutorials/how-to-get-element-value-in-puppeteer/)

---

**Note:** A similar question has been asked before:

> [Get the Value of HTML Attributes Using Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467696/get-the-value-of-html-attributes-using-puppeteer)