# Get the Value of HTML Attributes Using Puppeteer $x selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Since im trying to get HTML property for a element without class or ID

```
<span style="color: green">content</span>
```

I'm using $x selector:

```
const [data] = await page.$x('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span');

const style = await data.getProperty('style');
 
const pureStyle = await style.jsonValue();
```

But when I `console.log` pureStyle I receive as response:

```
{ '0': 'color' }
```

Comment: A bit more context and a runnable [mcve] would be great. Just because an element doesn't have a class or ID doesn't mean xpath is the best way to select it. What data were you expecting to log?

Comment: I was expecting to log { color: green } 

The getProperty seems to work fine with the eval methods
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467696/get-the-value-of-html-attributes-using-puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpliest way. You can get the span with `document.querySelectorAll()`. With this, you will have a list. Such as I don't know what return `page.$x`, maybe it return the same.

After, you have to get all style with `style` (what you do with `getProperty`). Such as you want only css content wrote in the html, you should use `cssText` and it will works fine.

Example:

```js
var span = document.querySelectorAll("div div div span");
for(var element of span) {
  console.log(element.style.cssText);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
       <span style="color: green; margin: 0;">span</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```