# Get the CSS attribute of an element outside the DOM world

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to find out of the 'display' of an element outside the DOM world.

If in the DOM world, you can use `getAttribute()`, what would be its counter-part?
I can't seem to get it using `JSHandle.getProperties()` or `JSHandle.getProperty('display').jsonValue()`

```
const loadingEl = await this.page.$('#app-container > main > div > div > div.infinite-loading-container > div:nth-child(1) > span')
const props = await loadingEl.getProperties()
const el = [] 
for (const property of props.values()) {
     const element = property.asElement();
           if (element) {
              el.push(element);
           }
}
console.log(el)
```

I'm trying to find out of the display is set to 'none'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Value of HTML Attributes Using Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467696/get-the-value-of-html-attributes-using-puppeteer)

Comment: @Cody Right idea, but current style values aren't really attributes.

Comment: sadly, this would still be done inside the DOM world. The website I"m scrapping would be alerted if I do any DOM world javascript operations hence I have to just get the `elementHandle` then do the operations from the Node environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `getComputedStyle` in an `eval` block to get the display value:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style>
p { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>can't see me</p>
</body>
</html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const display = await page.$eval(
    "p",
    el => getComputedStyle(el).display
  );
  console.log(display); // => none
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without using `eval()` or anything that would be done inside the DOM world? 

The website I'm scrapping would be alerted if I do any DOM world javascript. It fills up their error logs hence I would only get the `elementHandle` then do any operations in the node environment.

Comment: I see. Not that I'm aware of, unfortunately.